# How can i invoke AspxGridView Update

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to know if I can invoke AspxGridView update. I catch a data on AspxGridView Focused Row in server side. And if this data equles 0, I want to invoke update for this row. Else if this data equles 1, i want to invoke new row. Is it possible?

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that I don't use server side code. And this is my client side code:

```
 <ClientSideEvents FocusedRowChanged="function(s,e)
                        {                             
                          s.GetRowValues(s.GetFocusedRowIndex(),'FaturaVarmi',function(v){
                            switch(v)
                            {
                               case 0:                                                                       
                               case 1:
                               FaturaGrid.StartEditRow(s.GetFocusedRowIndex());
                               break;
                            }
                          })
                        }" />
```

Comment: There is also a ASPxGridView client side method for updating: [UpdateEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_UpdateEdittopic)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question but here's how to force the data update:

Call the Gridview's [UpdateEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_UpdateEdittopic) method.  To insert a new row, call the GridView's [AddNewRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_AddNewRowtopic) method.